# I generated a pdf, but when saving it's updating the same pdf instead of the new one

Tags: java, android, itext

I want to create a new document. Each time
current behavior updates old document rather than creating a new doc.

This is my code:

```
public void createPDF() throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {
    //create a new document file
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4,36,36,40,40);
    try {

        Log.e("PDFCreator", "PDF Path: " + path);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
        file = new File(dir, "Trinity PDF" + sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()) + ".pdf");
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fOut);
        writer.setPageEvent(new Watermark());
        //opening the document using doc
        doc.open();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to generate new pdf after every update....can anyone give solution

Comment: The problem is in the sdf.format method probably. Try using System.currentTimeMilis in order to check that.

Comment: Thanks this is working ....

Answer (score 2):

Thats probably because you are using same FILE name Each time .

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy")
```

this will give you same String for a day. So you just need to get a unique name each time.
If you want to show date in file name then you can use then you can use this format.

`SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");`

This will give a very big name You can make it as per your need. main thing is its should be unique each time.

Other then that you can also use [java.util.UUID](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html) or simply `System.currentTimeMillis()`